# sqlite unable to open database file when program is executed as subprocess

Tags: c++, python, sqlite, permissions, subprocess

I am facing the following problem: When I start my C++ written app directly it has no problems to connect to sqlite database file using sqlite3_open_v2(). But when I execute the app through a python script (with subprocess.Popen) I am always getting a

> "unable to open database file" error, when invoking sqlite3_open_v2()

I think this might be a problem with file permissions. But I set r/w permissions of the database file and of the containing folder to everyone.

Has someone an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: In your program, can you get a more thorough error? Like checking `errno` for example (using `perror` or `strerror`)? It might be that the folder paths are different for your application so the database file can not be found?

Comment: What OS are you on? (That might change the locking strategy.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I found the problem was a space to much in front of the name of the db (that is passed as argument to c++ app), did
subprocess.Popen(["prog", "-d {0}".format(PATH_TO_DB)])
should be
subprocess.Popen(["prog", "-d{0}".format(PATH_TO_DB)])